# UIImageView with 4 buttons

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to rotate the circle image like clock wise with 4 buttons(like imageview subviews) . it's rotating with buttons using core animation, but when i tap on any button it does not navigate another page, pls Help me

thanks in Advance

here i am giving my code

```
    CABasicAnimation *fullRotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    fullRotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
    fullRotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((360*M_PI)/180)];
    fullRotation.duration = 150.0f;
    fullRotation.repeatCount = 20.0;
    [self.image_Wheel addSubview:self.btn1];
    [self.image_Wheel addSubview:self.btn2];
    [self.image_Wheel addSubview:self.btn3];
    [self.image_Wheel addSubview:self.btn4];
    [self.image_Wheel.layer addAnimation:fullRotation forKey:@"360"];
```

Comment: Please provide more code to track the issue.Also add buttons functions in the code.

Comment: we would like to see navigation code on 'any button'

Comment: Is your image above your buttons ?

Comment: Place Break Point on Button Action Event see it fires or not. IF it does not fire than bring your button front as subview

Comment: @CrazyCreator image is bellow

Comment: Goutham: Please do not post comments requesting people to contact you and send you code. That's not what Stack Overflow is here for. There are other sites you can go to to hire freelancers to write code for you.

Answer (score 1):

Very good question. You should use a view and add all buttons and image on that. rotate view instead of image and button will work.

Comment: Please provide your code what you are trying I tried it and its working perfect
Take uiview
add uiimageview on uiview
add 4 button on UIView
rotate uiview
it will work

Comment: thanks for replay Mr. Monish Bansal,  i tried like that, in that way buttons are rotating through image, but button move some distance from starting point, when i tap on that button, view does not navigate to another

Comment: I think you are missing something. If you can please provide code. Here all are working fine.

Comment: i am using only xib, to set subview and imageView and all buttons. Just change the lost line of above code. i.e 
[self.subView addSubview:self.btn1];
[self.subView addSubview:self.image_Wheel];
[self.subView.layer addAnimation:fullRotation forKey:@"360"];
, if u don't mind pls provide your code, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Set `userInteractionEnabled` property of `UIImageView` to `YES`

Comment: thanks for reply, sorry, button action not working when button moves some distance.

Comment: make sure that the buttons are placed in bounds of imageView after transform , if the buttons placed out of imageView bound(frame) you wont get the button click

Comment: Also please make sure , you given the target for UIButton

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
self.image_Wheel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Also try to set the `btn` to the front.

Comment: thanks for reply, sorry, action not working when button moves some distance.

Comment: try to transform button similar to image transform, You are transforming image only not button.

Comment: without image transforms also image rotating clock wise

Comment: set background color to button n see where is your position of button & image, it may differ.